# Searching for numerical algorithm realization

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods

Im searching for numerical algorithm realization for nonlinear equations system solver on PHP, C, C++, Java (with readable code :). Where I can find them?

Thx.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thx. Asked on math too (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127373/searching-for-numerical-algorithm-realization) but Im thinking here I get answer more faster than on math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in [*Numerical Recipes*](http://www.nr.com/) -- the latest edition has reasonable C++ code.  Even if they don't have code to exactly solve your specific application, there's a good chance they have something you can use.